# Conditional image use based on current OS

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to make a docker-compose file that can solve my problem.

I want to run mongo on my raspberry pi but apparently there isn't a build for Pi, so I need to use a special image. I want to make a docker-compose file that will run the official mongo image if the OS can run it, or run the special image if I am on a Pi.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: place current os in .env file and in docker-compose file put condtion

Comment: Could you go into more detail please? I am still new to Docker in general.